# For spring data reactive cassandra when repository methods are called is the entire result of the query loaded to memory before returning a flux

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra, spring-reactor

I am *new to reactive programming*. Doing a POC on the **cassandra**/**datastax** with reactive spring data. I have executed some select query using the spring data **ReactiveCassandraRepository**. My doubt is about the internal working. When, for example, I trigger a findAll query it returns a Flux and I am able to see data using my REST client code. But my doubt is if I have 100 records as result of the query, will the spring data fetch those 100 records to memory and then stream it as Flux or is it actually when the client fetch for each row, the data is streaming all the way from database.

Comment: show your repository please, what return types did you use, you need Stream<> RT to get streaming behavior

Comment: I dont need to stream the real time data. What I am doing is issuing a select query using the spring reactive cassandra repository. My doubt is whether spring fetches the all records of the query to the memory and then create the Flux response or whether the interaction of spring repo to the Cassandra is also in the reactive way, that is, it issue a select query and don't wait for the response but immediately return a Flux to the client.

Comment: Here is my repository Interface:

public interface EventObjectRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<EventObject, EventObjectKey> {

 Flux<EventObject> findByEventObjectKeySystemId(UUID systemId);
}